# how to connect knobs in primefaces jsf

Tags: java, user-interface, jsf, primefaces

could someone tell me how to connect two or more knobs in primefaces?

I mean this thing
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/knob.xhtml

I would like to have something like
maxvalue = 100;
knob2.value = maxvalue - knob1.value

so if I set knob1 higher the other goes down

```
<h3>Colors</h3> 
    <div class="knob-container ui-corner-all">
        <p:knob foregroundColor="red" backgroundColor="#00000" value="#{knobView.value}">
            <p:ajax listener="#{knobView.onChange}"/>
        </p:knob>  
        <p:knob foregroundColor="blue" backgroundColor="#0000FF" value="#{knobView.value2}">
            <p:ajax listener="#{knobView.onChange}"/>
        </p:knob>  
    </div>
```

.

```
public void onChange(){  
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, 
            "val1: " + value + " " +
            "val2: " + value2           , null
            )); 
    this.value2 = maxval - this.value;

}
```

edit:
additional info 
I would like to have something like:
at start knob1= 50; knob2= 50
I set knob1 to 60 and knob2 goes automatically down to 40
I set knob1 to 10 and knob2 goes up to 90

Comment: it is a little unclear what you want can you please explain more?

Comment: Add your onChange method.

Comment: You want both to be paired?

Comment: Like so: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/dropdown.xhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 onChange methods and update after change the other knob.

**XHTML**

```
<div class="knob-container ui-corner-all">
    <p:knob id="knob_1" foregroundColor="red" backgroundColor="#00000"
        value="#{knobView.value1}">
        <p:ajax listener="#{knobView.onChange1()}" update="knob_2" />
    </p:knob>
    <p:knob id="knob_2" foregroundColor="blue" backgroundColor="#0000FF"
        value="#{knobView.value2}">
        <p:ajax listener="#{knobView.onChange2()}" update="knob_1" />
    </p:knob>
</div>
```

**Bean**

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class KnobView implements Serializable {

    int value1;
    int value2;
    int maxval = 100;
    // getter & setter

    public void onChange1() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                "val1: " + value1 + " " +
                        "val2: " + value2,
                null));
        this.value2 = maxval - value1;
    }

    public void onChange2() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                "val1: " + value1 + " " +
                        "val2: " + value2,
                null));
        this.value1 = maxval - value2;
    }

}
```

Comment: thx

do I need @ManagedBean(name="knobView") ?
I have not reachable bla bla without

but with @Named+@ManagedBean
it works partly, generates also new Knob circle, so after each event I got +1 more
but the numbers are correct for example knob1=7, knob2=25

I'll debug it ;) and read more about @Named

Comment: The ´@Named´ is for the binding between xhtml and bean. ´@ManagedBean(name="knobView")´ works also, but ´@ManagedBean´ is the old solution. Use only one. I preffer ´@Named´ and and CDI Scope.

Comment: it works with [ad]ManagedBean(name="knobView")
[ad]Named
[ad]SessionScoped

 with both but it is bugged because I should use only Named or Managed

with only named, I got "Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml [ad]18,39 value="#{knobView.value1}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'knobView' resolved to null"

Comment: There are two `@SessionScope`, use `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped`, `@Named` and getter/setter and it must work.

Comment: @w3Charlie: this is how you 'combine' any other two (or more) components too. See https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/dropdown.xhtml